# How to get Session Entities to work as part of Dialogflow detect intent

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have an Entity that is supposed to be updated on a per-session basis with user-specific information. This had worked when I was using Dialogflow v1, and I thought it had worked with v2, but I'm now having significant problems with it.

I believe I am setting the Session Entity information correctly, but for the Intent that uses it, it only matches when a value from the Developer Entity is used.

How can I get it to use the Session Entity? Am I doing something wrong when updating it? Am I using the wrong Session ID? Is there a way I can better verify or test that I'm using the correct ID or that I'm updating the Entity correctly? Is this just a bug?

Documentation of everything follows.

The project is configured to use v2 and to allow for beta features, although I've tried this without the beta features as well.

[image: configuration]

There are only three Intents. A Fallback Intent to capture failures, a Welcome Intent that gets the welcome event, and the "entry" intent that is supposed to capture the entry code which should match the "code" Entity. All of them use a webhook for fulfillment.
[image: intent list]

The Fallback Intent
[image: fallback intent]

The Welcome Intent
[image: welcome intent]

The "entry" Intent
[image: entry intent]

As shown in the "entry" Intent, it uses the "code" Entity, which is the only Developer Entity in the system

[image: code entity]

The code has most of the Dialogflow specific work in a separate module that uses the ["dialogflow" module from npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dialogflow) to set the Session Entity. (Note this is different than the dialogflow-fulfillment module, which is used to handle fulfillment. I'm using the multivocal library for fulfillment, but that shouldn't matter.) (It also uses firebase functions to run on, but I don't think any of these are relevant.)

From the package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "dialogflow": "^0.9.0",
    "firebase-admin": "~7.0.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^2.2.0",
    "multivocal": "^0.11.1"
  },
```

This is imported as `dialogflow`, specifying the API version to use:

```
const dialogflow = require('dialogflow').v2beta1;
```

The functions I show below call `envToConfig(env)` which takes the environment (a multivocal concept that just stores relevant information, including the Dialogflow `parent` and certificate information) and returns the configuration that needs to be passed to `dialogflow.SessionEntityTypesClient( config )`. Given no errors are thrown in further calls, it appears to work correctly.

The `makeEntityType( name, entityMap )` function takes a map of values to be used for the `entities` in a [SessionEntityType](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow-enterprise/docs/reference/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.environments.users.sessions.entityTypes#resource-sessionentitytype) and returns an object that will be used to build a full SessionEntityType. The `name` provided here is the display name.

```
function makeEntityType( name, entityMap ){
  let ret = {
    displayName: name,
    entities: []
  };

  Object.keys( entityMap ).map( key => {
    let val = entityMap[key];
    let entity = {
      value: key,
      synonyms: [key, ...val]
    };
    ret.entities.push( entity );
  });

  return ret;
}
exports.makeEntityType = makeEntityType;
```

The result from this is passed to `setSessionEntity( env, entityType )` along with the multivocal environment, which contains some information we use in the session. It makes sure the `name` and `entityOverrideMode` are set correctly in the `entityType` and then tries to create it. I've tried using PATCH as well, and it behaves the same way. It also does a bunch of logging, that I'll show later when it runs to prove it actually works.

```
function setSessionEntity( env, entityType ){
  const config = envToConfig( env );
  const client = new dialogflow.SessionEntityTypesClient( config );

  let parent = env.dialogflow.parent;
  if( entityType.displayName && !entityType.name ){
    entityType.name = `${parent}/entityTypes/${entityType.displayName}`;
  }
  if( !entityType.entityOverrideMode ){
    entityType.entityOverrideMode = 'ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_OVERRIDE';
  }

  console.log('setSessionEntity parent',parent);
  const request = {
    parent: parent,
    sessionEntityType: entityType
  };
  console.log('setSessionEntity request',JSON.stringify(request,null,1));
  return client.createSessionEntityType( request )
    .then( create => {
      console.log('setSessionEntity created',JSON.stringify(create,null,1));
      return Promise.resolve( env );
    })
    .catch( err => {
      console.error('setSessionEntity problem creating',err);
      return Promise.resolve( env );
    })
}
exports.setSessionEntity = setSessionEntity;
```

For debugging, I also have a function that lists the session entities:

```
function listSessionEntities( env ){
  let parent = env.dialogflow && env.dialogflow.parent;
  console.log('listSessionEntities parent', parent);
  if( !parent ){
    return Promise.resolve( env );
  }

  const config = envToConfig( env );
  const client = new dialogflow.SessionEntityTypesClient( config );
  const request = {
    parent: parent
  };
  return client.listSessionEntityTypes(request)
    .then( result => {
      console.log('listSessionEntities', JSON.stringify(result,null,1));
    })
    .catch( err => {
      console.log('listSessionEntities err', err);
    })
    .then( () => Promise.resolve( env ) );
}
exports.listSessionEntities = listSessionEntities;
```

The code that calls this imports it as `Dialogflow`:

```
const Dialogflow = require('./dialogflow');
```

As part of all the webhook calls, the `listSessionEntities()` function is called before any specific handler is:

```
function debugSessionEntities( env ){
  return Dialogflow.listSessionEntities( env );
}
```

When the Welcome Intent is triggered, it sets the "code" Session Entity to have two new types that should override the type that was defined in the "code" Developer Entity:

```
function handleWelcome( env ){
  const entityType = Dialogflow.makeEntityType('code',{
    'alpha': [],
    'bravo': []
  });
  return Dialogflow.setSessionEntity( env, entityType )
    .then( env => Multivocal.handleDefault( env ) );
}
```

When I run this through the simulator, it doesn't pick up on the Session Entity Types that are set, but do still respond to the Developer Entity Type. (Using a real device works the same way.)

[image: simulator conversation]

In the simulator, this is what it reports in the Request tab for the Welcome Intent:

```
{
  "responseId": "55a9eb06-ce05-48f9-8a56-b993fa512aee",
  "queryResult": {
    "queryText": "GOOGLE_ASSISTANT_WELCOME",
    "action": "multivocal.welcome",
    "parameters": {},
    "allRequiredParamsPresent": true,
    "fulfillmentText": "Hello! How can I help you?",
    "fulfillmentMessages": [
      {
        "text": {
          "text": [
            "Greetings! How can I assist?"
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "outputContexts": [
      {
        "name": "projects/session-test-XXXXX/agent/sessions/ABwppHFGTpcFtHOOo6ehQfKys9AnH14V5-RhzrNKsea6y6L5zgv4eN-j3IesfuqSsKMc7qRt1CAOhkUYA9XXXXXX/contexts/google_assistant_welcome"
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/session-test-XXXXX/agent/sessions/ABwppHFGTpcFtHOOo6ehQfKys9AnH14V5-RhzrNKsea6y6L5zgv4eN-j3IesfuqSsKMc7qRt1CAOhkUYA9XXXXXX/contexts/actions_capability_screen_output"
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/session-test-XXXXX/agent/sessions/ABwppHFGTpcFtHOOo6ehQfKys9AnH14V5-RhzrNKsea6y6L5zgv4eN-j3IesfuqSsKMc7qRt1CAOhkUYA9XXXXXX/contexts/actions_capability_audio_output"
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/session-test-XXXXX/agent/sessions/ABwppHFGTpcFtHOOo6ehQfKys9AnH14V5-RhzrNKsea6y6L5zgv4eN-j3IesfuqSsKMc7qRt1CAOhkUYA9XXXXXX/contexts/actions_capability_account_linking"
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/session-test-XXXXX/agent/sessions/ABwppHFGTpcFtHOOo6ehQfKys9AnH14V5-RhzrNKsea6y6L5zgv4eN-j3IesfuqSsKMc7qRt1CAOhkUYA9XXXXXX/contexts/google_assistant_input_type_keyboard"
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/session-test-XXXXX/agent/sessions/ABwppHFGTpcFtHOOo6ehQfKys9AnH14V5-RhzrNKsea6y6L5zgv4eN-j3IesfuqSsKMc7qRt1CAOhkUYA9XXXXXX/contexts/actions_capability_media_response_audio"
      },
      {
        "name": "projects/session-test-XXXXX/agent/sessions/ABwppHFGTpcFtHOOo6ehQfKys9AnH14V5-RhzrNKsea6y6L5zgv4eN-j3IesfuqSsKMc7qRt1CAOhkUYA9XXXXXX/contexts/actions_capability_web_browser"
      }
    ],
    "intent": {
      "name": "projects/session-test-XXXXX/agent/intents/ca79c951-4d75-4b2b-acd4-7dac2f81856e",
      "displayName": "welcome"
    },
    "intentDetectionConfidence": 1,
    "languageCode": "en-us"
  },
  "originalDetectIntentRequest": {
    "source": "google",
    "version": "2",
    "payload": {
      "isInSandbox": true,
      "surface": {
        "capabilities": [
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.ACCOUNT_LINKING"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
          },
          {
            "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
          }
        ]
      },
      "requestType": "SIMULATOR",
      "inputs": [
        {
          "rawInputs": [
            {
              "query": "Talk to my test app",
              "inputType": "KEYBOARD"
            }
          ],
          "intent": "actions.intent.MAIN"
        }
      ],
      "user": {
        "userStorage": "{\"UserId\":\"ABwppHHd40lIZ1o0bRERAKlHNtNcS2qFtz7NbRQnb31AQDFuV41VPFQivXwwpQGtv_5SlsZNp0N3kxalIIXXXXXX\",\"NumVisits\":1}",
        "lastSeen": "2019-05-18T19:12:38Z",
        "locale": "en-US",
        "userId": "ABwppHHd40lIZ1o0bRERAKlHNtNcS2qFtz7NbRQnb31AQDFuV41VPFQivXwwpQGtv_5SlsZNp0N3kxalIIXXXXXX"
      },
      "conversation": {
        "conversationId": "ABwppHFGTpcFtHOOo6ehQfKys9AnH14V5-RhzrNKsea6y6L5zgv4eN-j3IesfuqSsKMc7qRt1CAOhkUYA9XXXXXX",
        "type": "NEW"
      },
      "availableSurfaces": [
        {
          "capabilities": [
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
            },
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
            },
            {
              "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "session": "projects/session-test-XXXXX/agent/sessions/ABwppHFGTpcFtHOOo6ehQfKys9AnH14V5-RhzrNKsea6y6L5zgv4eN-j3IesfuqSsKMc7qRt1CAOhkUYA9XXXXXX"
}
```

Most notable from that is the `session` attribute set at the bottom from that. The code uses this as the `parent` and `session` values when building the

The request objects for the other two Intents are similar, and all have the same value for `session`. None of the response objects are notable in any way.

When the Welcome Intent is triggered, the call to `listSessionEntities()`, unsurprisingly, shows there aren't any yet:

```
info: listSessionEntities parent projects/session-test-XXXXX/agent/sessions/ABwppHFGTpcFtHOOo6ehQfKys9AnH14V5-RhzrNKsea6y6L5zgv4eN-j3IesfuqSsKMc7qRt1CAOhkUYA9XXXXXX
info: listSessionEntities [
 [],
 null,
 null
]
```

The `parent` appears to have the correct value from the `session` however.

When the handler for the Welcome Intent goes and creates the Session Entity, things appear to work ok:

```
info: setSessionEntity request {
 "parent": "projects/session-test-XXXXX/agent/sessions/ABwppHFGTpcFtHOOo6ehQfKys9AnH14V5-RhzrNKsea6y6L5zgv4eN-j3IesfuqSsKMc7qRt1CAOhkUYA9XXXXXX",
 "sessionEntityType": {
  "displayName": "code",
  "entities": [
   {
    "value": "alpha",
    "synonyms": [
     "alpha"
    ]
   },
   {
    "value": "bravo",
    "synonyms": [
     "bravo"
    ]
   }
  ],
  "name": "projects/session-test-XXXXX/agent/sessions/ABwppHFGTpcFtHOOo6ehQfKys9AnH14V5-RhzrNKsea6y6L5zgv4eN-j3IesfuqSsKMc7qRt1CAOhkUYA9XXXXXX/entityTypes/code",
  "entityOverrideMode": "ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_OVERRIDE"
 }
}
info: setSessionEntity created [
 {
  "entities": [
   {
    "synonyms": [
     "alpha"
    ],
    "value": "alpha"
   },
   {
    "synonyms": [
     "bravo"
    ],
    "value": "bravo"
   }
  ],
  "name": "projects/session-test-XXXXX/agent/sessions/ABwppHFGTpcFtHOOo6ehQfKys9AnH14V5-RhzrNKsea6y6L5zgv4eN-j3IesfuqSsKMc7qRt1CAOhkUYA9XXXXXX/entityTypes/code",
  "entityOverrideMode": "ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_OVERRIDE"
 },
 null,
 null
]
```

The `parent` appears to be the same as the `session`, and the `name` appears to follow the correct format, including the additional part that has the "/entityTypes/" followed by the display name.

When I try calling it with the code "alpha", which should trigger the "entry" Intent, it instead triggers the Fallback Intent. The call to `listSessionEntities()` seems to show the "code" Entity with the Entity Types we expect, even tho there was no match for "alpha".

```
info: listSessionEntities parent projects/session-test-XXXXX/agent/sessions/ABwppHFGTpcFtHOOo6ehQfKys9AnH14V5-RhzrNKsea6y6L5zgv4eN-j3IesfuqSsKMc7qRt1CAOhkUYA9XXXXXX
info: listSessionEntities [
 [
  {
   "entities": [
    {
     "synonyms": [
      "alpha"
     ],
     "value": "alpha"
    },
    {
     "synonyms": [
      "bravo"
     ],
     "value": "bravo"
    }
   ],
   "name": "projects/session-test-XXXXX/agent/sessions/ABwppHFGTpcFtHOOo6ehQfKys9AnH14V5-RhzrNKsea6y6L5zgv4eN-j3IesfuqSsKMc7qRt1CAOhkUYA9XXXXXX/entityTypes/code",
   "entityOverrideMode": "ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_OVERRIDE"
  }
 ],
 null,
 null
]
```

Again, everything looks correct. When I try it again with "zulu", it shows the same thing for the call to `listSessionEntites()`, but this time it matches the "entry" Intent, since "zulu" is one of the Entity Types for "code" that is defined as a Developer Entity.

This is where I am stuck. Everything *looks* correct. It looks like the Session Entity should be set correctly **for this session**. It looks like it should be using those values. But it never seems to do so.

What is going on? All help would be *greatly* appreciated. (Did you even read till the end of the question? If so - thank you! I know it's long, but wanted to be as complete as possible.)

Answer (score 6):

This appears to be a bug - I've gotten feedback from other developers that they're seeing the same problem, sometimes on previously working code.

A bug has been opened at https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/133166381 to track the issue. Star it to indicate you have similar problems and to track progress.